# can't achieve touch compatibility with my jQuery zoom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch, zooming

I modified an MIT licensed Zoom Plugins to fit my needs and it works perfectly well. However, it came from a time before smartphones and tablets and I really want to support them.

I have built a jsFiddle to illustrate my case:
    https://jsfiddle.net/xLr86bs8/

Neccessary code:

JavaScript:

```
(function($){

var defaults = {
cursorColor:'237,241,244',
cursorOpacity: 1,
//cursorBorder: '1px solid black',
//cursorBorderThickness: 1,
cursor:'pointer',
zoomviewsize: [0,0],
magnification: 5,

};

var minitraversalzoomCursor,minitraversalzoomView,minitraversalsettings,minitraversalImageWidth,minitraversalImageHeight,minitraversalOffset,minitraversalzoomimage;
var minitraversalMethods = {
init : function(options){
  $this = $(this),
  minitraversalzoomCursor = $('.minitraversalzoom-cursor'),
  minitraversalzoomView = $('.minitraversalzoom-view'),
  minitraversalzoomimage = $('#MiniTraversalZoomImage'),


  // This makes the complete addon independent from the size of the zoomwindow
  //defaults.zoomviewsize = [$('#RadialBox').width(),$('#RadialBox').height()];




  $(document).on('mouseenter touchstart',$this.selector,function(e){

    var data = $(this).data();
    minitraversalsettings = $.extend({},defaults,options,data);
    minitraversalOffset = $(this).offset();
    minitraversalImageWidth = $(this).width();
    minitraversalImageHeight = $(this).height();
    minitraversalsettings.zoomviewsize = [$(this).parent().width(),$(this).parent().height()];

    cursorSize = [(minitraversalsettings.zoomviewsize[0]/minitraversalsettings.magnification),(minitraversalsettings.zoomviewsize[1]/minitraversalsettings.magnification)];

    $original = $(this);



    minitraversalZoomSource = $(this).attr('data-minitraversalzoom');
    minitraversalSource = $(this).attr('src');

    var posX = e.pageX,posY = e.pageY,zoomViewPositionX;
    $('body').prepend('<div class="minitraversalzoom-cursor">&nbsp;</div>');
    $('#MiniZoomBox').addClass('minitraversalzoom-view').prepend('<img id="MiniTraversalZoomImage" src="' + minitraversalZoomSource + '">');








    $(minitraversalzoomView.selector).css({
      'position':'relative',
      'z-index': 7,
      'overflow':'hidden',
    });

    $(minitraversalzoomView.selector).children('img[id="MiniTraversalZoomImage"]').css({
      'position':'relative',
      'width': minitraversalImageWidth*minitraversalsettings.magnification,
      'height': minitraversalImageHeight*minitraversalsettings.magnification,

    });







    $(minitraversalzoomCursor.selector).css({
      'position':'absolute',
      'width':cursorSize[0],
      'height':cursorSize[1],
      'background-color':'rgb('+ minitraversalsettings.cursorColor +')',
      'z-index': 7,
      'opacity':minitraversalsettings.cursorOpacity,
      'cursor':minitraversalsettings.cursor,
      'border':minitraversalsettings.cursorBorder,
    });




    $(minitraversalzoomCursor.selector).css({'top':posY-(cursorSize[1]/2),'left':posX});
    $(document).on('mousemove move',document.body,minitraversalMethods.cursorPos);


  });
},





cursorPos:function(e){
  var posX = e.pageX,posY = e.pageY;
  if(posY < minitraversalOffset.top || posX < minitraversalOffset.left || posY > (minitraversalOffset.top+minitraversalImageHeight) || posX > (minitraversalOffset.left+minitraversalImageWidth)){

    $(minitraversalzoomCursor.selector).remove();
    $(minitraversalzoomimage.selector).remove();

    //$(minitraversalzoomView.selector).empty();
    //$('#ZoomImage').remove();
    //$(this).siblings('img').remove();

    //$('#RadialBox > img').remove();
    //$('#MiniZoomBox > img[id!="TraversalZoomImage10x"]').remove();
    $('#MiniZoomBox').removeClass('minitraversalzoom-view');//.append('<img data-minitraversalzoom="' + minitraversalZoomSource + '" src="' + minitraversalSource + '" class="minitraversalzoom">');        
    //$('#MiniZoomBox').empty().removeClass('minitraversalzoom-view').append('<img data-minitraversalzoom="' + minitraversalZoomSource + '" src="' + minitraversalSource + '" class="minitraversalzoom">');
    //$('#RadialBox').removeClass('minitraversalzoom-view').prepend($original.prop('outerHTML'));


    return;
  }



  if(posX-(cursorSize[0]/2) < minitraversalOffset.left){
    posX = minitraversalOffset.left+(cursorSize[0]/2);
  }else if(posX+(cursorSize[0]/2) > minitraversalOffset.left+minitraversalImageWidth){
    posX = (minitraversalOffset.left+minitraversalImageWidth)-(cursorSize[0]/2);
  }

  if(posY-(cursorSize[1]/2) < minitraversalOffset.top){
    posY = minitraversalOffset.top+(cursorSize[1]/2);
  }else if(posY+(cursorSize[1]/2) > minitraversalOffset.top+minitraversalImageHeight){
    posY = (minitraversalOffset.top+minitraversalImageHeight)-(cursorSize[1]/2);
  }







  $(minitraversalzoomCursor.selector).css({'top':posY-(cursorSize[1]/2),'left':posX-(cursorSize[0]/2)});
  $(minitraversalzoomView.selector).children('img').css({'top':((minitraversalOffset.top-posY)+(cursorSize[1]/2))*minitraversalsettings.magnification,'left':((minitraversalOffset.left-posX)+(cursorSize[0]/2))*minitraversalsettings.magnification});





  /*
  $(minitraversalzoomCursor.selector).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });*/

}
};

$.fn.minitraversalZoom = function(method){
if(minitraversalMethods[method]){
  return minitraversalMethods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
}else if( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return minitraversalMethods.init.apply(this,arguments);
}else{
  $.error(method);
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-minitraversalzoom]').minitraversalZoom();
});
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="ZoomWindow" id="MiniZoomBox"><img class="minitraversalzoom" data-minitraversalzoom="http://placekitten.com/234/351" src="http://placekitten.com/234/351"/></div>

    <div class=""></div>
```

CSS:

```
.ZoomWindowContainer{
    display: inline-block;  
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}



.ZoomWindow{
/*  display: inline-block;
*/  height: 351px;
    width: 234px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #a3b7c7;
}






#MiniZoomBox > img.miniradialzoom, #MiniZoomBox > img.minitraversalzoom, #MiniZoomBox > img.minitangentialzoom{
    height: 100%;

}


#MiniZoomBox{
    background-color: #0072bd;
    /*background: url("/css/styling/magnifier_background-gradient-right.png") repeat-y scroll 0% 0% transparent;*/
/*  background: url('/css/styling/10x.png') #0072bd;
*/  background-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Could somebody help me to tweek it, in order to make it work?

Update:
I implemented the jQuery.event.move plugin to get new options like movestart, move, etc… and with it, I could get my plugin to work correctly on touchscreens, however, scrolling does not work at all on the site now. So i solved one problem and got another one. Does anyone know, to fix either one of them?

Update Jan. 1st 2016:
I continued programming and this is still the last problem I am facing. Any help is welcomed here ;)